# Pyspark replace strings in Spark dataframe column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like to perform some basic stemming on a Spark Dataframe column by replacing substrings. What's the quickest way to do this?

In my current use case, I have a list of addresses that I want to normalize. For example this dataframe:

```
id     address
1       2 foo lane
2       10 bar lane
3       24 pants ln
```

Would become

```
id     address
1       2 foo ln
2       10 bar ln
3       24 pants ln
```

Comment: What's your Spark version?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

For Spark 1.5 or later, you can use the [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html?highlight=regexp_replace#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) package:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
newDf = df.withColumn('address', regexp_replace('address', 'lane', 'ln'))
```

Quick explanation:

- The function `withColumn` is called to add (or replace, if the name exists) a column to the data frame.
- The function `regexp_replace` will generate a new column by replacing all substrings that match the pattern.

Comment: Just remember that the first parameter of regexp_replace refers to the column being changed, the second is the regex to find and the last is how to replace it.

Comment: can I use regexp_replace inside a pipeline? Thanks

Comment: Can we change more than one item in this code?

Comment: @elham you can change any value that fits a regexp **expression** for one column using this function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/R/regexp_replace.html

Comment: How does it work for subtracting two [string columns within a single dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69540138/10452700) in PySpark?

Comment: Can this be adapted to replace only if entire string is matched and not substring? i.e., if I wanted to replace 'lane' by 'ln' but keep 'skylane' unchanged?

Answer (score 11):

For scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
data.withColumn("addr_new", regexp_replace(col("addr_line"), "\\*", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to import the sql `function` package and make use of `withColumn` function to modify the existing column in the df. In this case we need to replace address column data having lane as `ln`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

replacedf = df.withColumn('address', regexp_replace('address', 'lane', 'ln'))
```