# Pyspark replace strings in Spark dataframe column by using values in another column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to replace a value present in a column with by creating search string from another column

before

`id address     st

1  2.PA1234.la 1234 
2  10.PA125.la 125
3  2.PA156.ln 156`

After

`id address     st

1  2.PA9999.la 1234 
2  10.PA9999.la 125
3  2.PA9999.ln 156`

I tried

```
df.withColumn("address", regexp_replace("address","PA"+st,"PA9999"))
df.withColumn("address",regexp_replace("address","PA"+df.st,"PA9999")
```

both seam to fail with

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

could be similar to 
[Pyspark replace strings in Spark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038014/pyspark-replace-strings-in-spark-dataframe-column)

Comment: Regex: `(?<=PA)[^\.]+`, substitution: `9999`

Comment: thank you very much @S.Jovan , it worked as expected :)

Answer (score 2):

You might also use the spark udf.

The solution might be applied whenever you need to modify a data frame entry with a value from another column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

pd_input = pd.DataFrame({'address': ['2.PA1234.la','10.PA125.la','2.PA156.ln'],
             'st':['1234','125','156']})

spark_df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(pd_input)


replace_udf = udf(lambda address, st: address.replace(st,'9999'), StringType())

spark_df.withColumn('adress_new',replace_udf(col('address'),col('st'))).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+----+------------+
|     adress|  st|  adress_new|
+-----------+----+------------+
|2.PA1234.la|1234| 2.PA9999.la|
|10.PA125.la| 125|10.PA9999.la|
| 2.PA156.ln| 156| 2.PA9999.ln|
+-----------+----+------------+
```