# Convert string with dollar sign into numbers

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a string column with dollar signs in it. How can I convert into doubletype or float so that I can do calculation on it?

The columns looks like '$1000,000.28'.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use regexp or replace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark replace strings in Spark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038014/pyspark-replace-strings-in-spark-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace` function and cast to double.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df.withColumn('new_value', f.regexp_replace('value', '[$,]', '').cast('double'))
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(10, False)

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_value: double (nullable = true)

+---+------------+----------+
|id |value       |new_value |
+---+------------+----------+
|1  |$1000,000.28|1000000.28|
+---+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.replace to remove the $ sign, and then you can convert the string into an float just with float().

```
money = '$12,345'
money = money.replace('$','') .replace(',','') #this replaces the $ and , in the string
money = float(money)
```