# Using Replace() Python function in Pyspark Sql context

Tags: python, pyspark

```
gsh_uk_id = gsh_uk_id.withColumn("id", f.when(1, gsh_uk_id["id"].replace(".","??")).otherwise(gsh_uk_id["id"]))
```

it is showing error: `'Column' object is not callable`

i want to replace "." character in each entry of column "id" of table gsh_uk_id with "??".

Please help me with that thankyou.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark replace strings in Spark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038014/pyspark-replace-strings-in-spark-dataframe-column)

Comment: gsh_uk.show(5)

+-------+
|     id|
+-------+
|ajs1q·0|
|ajuy9·0|
|ak57k·0|
|akyri·0|
|alcxf·0|
+-------+
only showing top 5 rows


new_gsh_uk = gsh_uk.withColumn('id', regexp_replace('id', '.', '??'))

new_gsh_uk.show(5)

+--------------+
|            id|
+--------------+
|??????????????|
|??????????????|
|??????????????|
|??????????????|
|??????????????|
+--------------+
only showing top 5 rows